# Which Japanese font for a title page of a physics book?

Tags: fonts, japanese

In the European editions of the free Motion Mountain physics book I use the MinionPro font (see http://www.motionmountain.net/online.html for the English typography). Now, Hirooka Megumi is translating the book into Japanese, and he says that the font used so far is not good enough for a title page. So far, we only set the text in Japanese, as shown in http://www.motionmountain.net/japanese.html on the top of the web page. I did so using \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min} ... \end{CJK} because this was the easiest thing to do. But it seems that for a title font this does not look well; especially the kanji are not beautiful enough. The present attempt for a title page is shown at the bottom of that same web page.

Now, to avoid an opinion-based question:

Which other Japanese latex font could I install and use for the title page? Are other fonts all installed and used in the same way in Japanese latex? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You are asking for a good looking font. This is opinion based and also off-topic here.

Comment: choice of font is generally off topic here (you could ask on the graphic design site perhaps).  If you use xelatex or lualatex you could use any fonts on your system, so just get your translator to specify a font he or she likes.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, please don't use CJK, because you cannot use better fonts. Use either one of the Japanese engines (platex, uplatex) or lualatex with luatexja. 
Then please look at the package jfontmaps which gives a long list of fonts supported, both free and non-free. Depending on whether you possess these fonts, Hiragino or Morisawa are good ones. Kozuka you get for free with Adobe Reader, but it is not clear whether you can use the font for your book.
From options there are a few, IPAex, M+, Noto Sans, hard to say which fonts you prefer.
Please contact me for more detailed discussion, I'm one of the authors of jfontmaps.